# Reset timezone aware timestamp momentjs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using momentjs for doing my date operations and want to code a scenario where if timestamp is given, and timezone name is given, then I want to reset the time to  midnight. For e.g.

```
let timestamp = 1493638245234;
expect(new Date(timestamp).toISOString()).toBe('2017-05-01T11:30:45.234Z'); // Time in UTC
let truncatedTimestamp = functionName(timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(truncatedTimestamp); 
expect(new Date(truncatedTimestamp)).toBe('2017-05-01T04:00:00.000Z'); 


const functionName = (timestamp, timezone) => {
return moment
    .tz(timestamp, timezone)
    .startOf('day')
    .toDate()
    .getTime();
};
```

I would like the function `'functionName'` to return midnight of `America/Los_Angeles` time and not in UTC.

The timestamp I entered is 5th May 2017, 11:30 AM UTC.
I expect the function to return me timestamp for 5th May 2017, 00:00 `America/Los_Angeles` (Since 5th May 2017 11:30 AM UTC will be 11:30 AM -7 hours in `America/Los_Angeles`.) and convert it to milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove `toDate()` that gives a JavaScript date object using local time. Then you can use [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) instead of `getTime()`.

> `moment#valueOf` simply outputs the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, just like `Date#valueOf`.

Your code could be like the following:

```js
const functionName = (timestamp, timezone) => {
  return moment(timestamp)
      .tz(timezone)
      .startOf('day')
      .valueOf();
};

let timestamp = 1493638245234;
let truncatedTimestamp = functionName(timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(truncatedTimestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.17/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Note that [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) and [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) are equivalent in your case (since you are passing millis).

Answer (score 1):

I modified my function functionName to be like this and it worked.

```
const functionName = (timestamp, timezone) =>
    moment
        .tz(timestamp, timezone)
        .startOf('day')
        .valueOf();
```

NOTE: Some user posted this answer, but they deleted their answer.

Comment: I've undeleted my answer, sorry for temporarily deletion. I had some doubts about the code after posting the answer, but I was on mobile with limited chances to check it (late night on my timezone didn't help either :D).